# Linq to SQL Grouping Child Relationships

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to run a LINQ to SQL query that returns a result in a grid view in a search engine style listing.

In the simplified example below, is it possible to populate the collection with a comma-separated list of any children that the parent has (NAMESOFCHILDREN) in a single query?

```
var family = from p in db.Parents
             where p.ParentId == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["parentId"])
             join pcl in db.ParentChildLookup on p.ParentId equals pcl.ParentId
             join c in db.Children on pcl.ChildId equals c.ChildId
             select new
             {
                 Family = "Name: " + p.ParentName + "<br />" + 
                          "Children: " + NAMESOFCHILDREN? + "<br />"
             };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your joins are going to screw up your cardinality!  You don't have a list of Parents!

Here's some untested free-hand code.  Adding the relationships in the Linq designer gives you relationship properties.  String.Join will put the list together.

I've added two optional method calls.

*Where ... Any*  will filter the parents to only those parents that have children.  I'm unsure of string.Join's behavior on an empty array.

*ToList* will yank Parents into memory, the children will be accessed by further database calls.  This may be necessary if you get a runtime *string.Join is not supported by SQL translator* exception.  This exception would mean that LINQ tried to translate the method call into something that SQL Server can understand - and failed.

```
int parentID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["parentId"]);

List<string> result =
  db.Parents
  .Where(p => p.ParentId == parentID)
  //.Where(p => p.ParentChildLookup.Children.Any())
  //.ToList()
  .Select(p => 
    "Name: " + p.ParentName + "<br />" + 
    "Children: " + String.Join(", ", p.ParentChildLookup.Children.Select(c => c.Name).ToArray() + "<br />"
)).ToList();
```

Also note: generally you do not want to mix data and markup until the data is properly escaped for markup.

Comment: Thanks.  I decided to display this data in a different way but this got me going in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

you could try as follow:

```
var family = from p in db.Parents            
     where p.ParentId == Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["parentId"])             
    join pcl in db.ParentChildLookup on p.ParentId equals pcl.ParentId             
     select new             {                 
        Family = "Name: " + p.ParentName + "<br />" + string.Join(",",(from c in db.Children where c.ChildId equals pcl.ChildId  select c.ChildId.ToString()).ToArray());
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Posting an answer for an old question with `groupby`. Below query will produce company name, order count and order ids separated by comma from Northwind.

```
var query = from c in north.Customers
                    join o in north.Orders on c.CustomerID equals o.CustomerID
                    select new { c, o };

        var query2 = from q in query
                     group q.o by q.c into g
                     select new { CompanyName = g.Key.CompanyName, 
                                orderCount = g.Count(), 
                                orders = string.Join(",", g.Select(o => o.OrderID)) }
                     into result
                         orderby result.orderCount descending
                     select result;
```